# No Wireless, anywhere

Tags: networking

Hey I'm super new to Linux and I do not know how to turn the Wireless on, the Wifi has this wierd symbol kind of like a sideways Bluetooth icon with a cross over it, any ideas how to fix it? Even in my System Settings > Network there is Wired, but no WireLESS to be seen!!

Please help!!
I am using a HP Laptop running the current latest version of EOS.

Comment: I think didn't recognize you wireless so try:<br/>
`sudo lshw -c network`<br/>
and find driver then google you wireless drive and install.

Comment: Please add more info about your system if you still need help.